# Find String and extract with next String

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that contains an address. I would like to check if the address contains the word 'Flat' and if it does, extract the flat number next to it.

- The flat number can be one, two, three or four digits.
- The word 'flat' can appear in any part of the string (i.e. not just at the beginning) - but only once.

Here is an example string:

```
Flat 62, Selig Court, Beverley Gardens, London
```

Or

```
Selig Court, Flat 62, Beverley Gardens, London
```

I would like the result to be:

```
Flat 62
```

I am attempting to do this in JavaScript.

Comment: and you cannot google regex generator?

Comment: I feel like this is a homework you didn't even attempt to solve :(

Comment: `I am attempting to do this in JavaScript.` Please post the code you are currently having issues with so we can have a look why your attempt isn't working. Using your code, please see [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - As it stands your question should be closed as `primarily opinion-based` or similar as you have given no indication how you wish to solve this problem but simply posted requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Based on exactly what you said:-

```
> "Selig Court, Flat 62, Beverley Gardens, London".match(/(Flat \d{1,4})/)[0]
'Flat 62'
> "Flat 62, Selig Court, Beverley Gardens, London".match(/(Flat \d{1,4})/)[0]
'Flat 62'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex

```
/Flat\s+(\d+)/gi
```

Explanation

- `Flat\s+` allows one or more spaces after `Flat`
- `(\d+)` matches the digits

Example

```
"Flat 62, Selig Court, Beverley Gardens, London".match(/Flat\s(\d+)/gi); //["Flat 62"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the few lines that ought to do the trick.
String is there just for demo, like console.log, lets focus on the meat of the example.

myRegexp is a regular expression, I will use it to try capture from string. Keep in mind you have to define it in between //. As for it's contents, I match either a flat or Flat followed by space then a 1-4 digits. This is based on info you provided. So it won't work on let's say Flat1 or FLAT 33.

```
var myString = "Flat 62, Selig Court, Beverley Gardens, London";
var myRegexp = /((Flat|flat) \d{1,4})/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
console.log(match[1]);
```

For a match I am simply saying hey regex, exec on this string and save capture groups. If there is a match with given string capture group gets your info out.

See the solution in action on 2 examples you gave:

[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jq4saxby/1/)

I explained only the core or rather the cookbook how problem can be approached. If you gonna use regexes in practice there is a LOT more to learn about them. Google is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

you can see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FLXY6AMLGLZU) example :

```
    var str = "Flat 62, Selig Court, Beverley Gardens, London";
    var patt1 = /\w+\s\d+/g; 
    var result = str.match(patt1);
```